# Linux and serial console delaying kernel load?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot

This issue suddenly showed up on my main machine and I didn't quite understand it: when booting a Linux kernel image (versions 4.15.0_32/33/34) with the default grub generated arguments:

```
console tty0 console ttyS0 panic=-1
```

the kernel load time jumps from the usual 1-2 seconds to almost 20 seconds. Userspace loading is also noticeably slower and takes up to 30 seconds. The whole boot time is around 1:16 minutes, measured using `systemd-analyze`.
I scratched my head trying to understand why, and then realized that removing the `console ttyS0` argument or disabling the serial com from the EFI BIOS solves the problem.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you mis-spelt what you removed?  Or did you really remove `tty0`?

Comment: Mispelled actually, thank you :) fixing it

Comment: That's not surprising -- the default 9600 bits/sec is slow, and linux writes a lot of stuff when booting up. Try setting the speed to something faster (with eg. console=ttyS0,115200n8) and see if that makes things more tolerable.

Comment: @mosvy I tried and it actually sped up the whole thing. My point is that the issue was **not** present the day before, and it just popped out. No updates made in between.

Comment: linux is using only the first console for displaying its messages -- and I'm not really sure that there is some stable order in which they're initialized (I cannot check that now, unfortunately). Maybe you were lucky and it was always choosing tty0 instead of ttyS0 until yesterday ;-)

Anyways, if you don't use the serial console, you can safely disable it.

Comment: anyway even at 115200 bits/s it's still slower than a tty video console